# Live sass compiler not loading modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, module, live

I'm trying to load a member in my main style file.

Here is the file structure

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SVI8.png)

Here is the code from _body_style.scss

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Then code code from main_style.scss

```
@use '_body_style';
```

And this is the output in main_style.css

```
@use '_body_style';
/*# sourceMappingURL=main_style.css.map */
```

The compiler is not loading the module and I don't see any errors in console

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7oNv.png)

Is there any configuration I'm missing or am I doing it wrong? I used this before for a different project and I don't remember having such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks

**Well, the problem is caused by the Visual Studio Code extension you are using for compiling SASS or SCSS files to CSS files.**

#### Don't use this extension: Live Sass Compiler by Ritwick Dey

You are probably using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) extension: Live Sass Compiler by Ritwick Dey. It's widely used, but is no longer supported by the author. Consequently, the SASS version isn't updated. This extension produces the error you are describing.

#### Use this extension: Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks

You should use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass) extension: Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks. As the author states: *A big thank you to @ritwickdey for all his work. However, as they are no longer maintaining the original work, I have released my own which has been built upon it.* This extension compiles your SASS or SCSS files to CSS files successfully.

Comment: It's not working. I'll try reinstalling the extension in vscode

Comment: I updated my answer. Use Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks, not Ritwick Dey.

Comment: Yeah that solved the problem. It seems that Ritwick's extension is not longer supported, and it's bit outdated. That explains why it only supports '@import' and not '@use'. Thank's a lot!